# std::ifstream::read or std::ofstream::write with a zero parameter?

Tags: c++, file, stream, zero, standards-compliance

Is it perfectly ok (= well defined behaviour according to the standard) to call :

```
mystream.read(buffer, 0);
```

or

```
mystream.write(buffer, 0);
```

(and of course nothing will be read or written). 
I would like to know if I have to test if the provided size is null before calling one of these two functions.

Comment: u have made a special case of making the size 0..nothing else

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing bad will happen.

Comment: @Archimaredes, I'm uncertain.  I vaguely recall MSVC firing an assert when I tried this.  Are you certain?

Comment: I would be disappointed if anything bad happened. But whatever the standard says edge cases like this are buggy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is well-defined: both functions will go through the motions for unformatted input/output functions (constructing the sentry, setting failbit if eofbit is set, flushing the tied stream if necessary), and then they will get to this clause:

§27.7.2.3[istream.unformatted]/30

> Characters are extracted and stored until either of the following occurs:
>
> — n characters are stored;

§27.7.3.7[ostream.unformatted]/5

> Characters are inserted until either of the following occurs
>
> — n characters are inserted;

"zero characters are stored/inserted" is true before anything is stored or extracted.

Looking at actual implementations, I see `for (; gcount < n; ++gcount)` [in libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/istream) or `sgetn(buffer, n);` [in stdlibc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc?view=markup) which has the [equivalent loop](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/streambuf.tcc?view=markup)

Answer (score 0):

Another extraction from `27.7.2.3 Unformatted input functions/1` gives us a clue that zero-size input buffers are valid case:

> unformatted input functions taking a character array of **non-zero size** as an argument shall also store a null character (using charT()) in the first location of the array.