# std::iostream read or write with count zero and invalid buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, ostream, istream

The following code reads a file containing some value that represents the length of more following data.

```
auto file = std::ifstream(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
// dataLen = Read some header field containing a length of following data.
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
data.resize(dataLen);
file.read((char*)data.data(), dataLen);
```

It fails with the MSVC 2013 compiler if `dataLen = 0`. It causes an abort with the message `Expression: invalid null pointer`, because `data.data()` returns a null pointer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014192/stdifstreamread-or-stdofstreamwrite-with-a-zero-parameter)  suggests that a `count` of 0 is valid for `std::basic_istream::read`, but the third comment on the question seems to point out my issue.

Is it valid C++ to pass an invalid pointer to `std::basic_istream::read` (or `std::basic_ostream::write`) with a size of 0? It would seem logical to me, because the call should not touch the buffer anyway.

The obvious solution is to deal with this special case with an if clause, but I am wondering if MSVC is wrong once again.

Here is a compiled example of clang running the program fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c036ec31abd80f22

Comment: For clarification, "It causes an abort with the message..." - is that triggered by an uncaught *exception*? Or is it a runtime *assertion* in the debug-binaries of the VS standard C++ libraries. It may not seem a big difference, but it is relevant. And does the same behavior rear in a *release* build ?

Comment: @WhozCraig It says `Debug Assertion Failed!` and does not happen in a release build.

Comment: @typ1232 So why not in debug mode just do `data.resize(dataLen + 1)`?

Comment: @Barry because later usage of `data.size()` is no longer accurate to the size of the actually-read data. Though a followup-data.`resize(dataLen);` would address that, all of the above is somewhat the point of the OP's question: Should such hoops be required in the first place.

Comment: @typ1232 I suspected as much. MS is trying to be "helpful" by telling you the passed-in pointer is invalid. That assertion should have included a validation that the claimed buffer size was non-zero as well. In reviewing the standard, there is a single-char write to the buffer even if no data is extracted, but it is hinged on a non-zero length being passed. But in your case said-length is zero, so that shouldn't apply. If MS were throwing a runtime exception I would find it deplorable (not unfamiliar ground for MS), but as-is I can only classify it as just-plain irritating.

Comment: I should point out first that `data.data()` should NOT be an invalid pointer, but a valid pointer that points to an empty range. On the other hand, using a truly invalid pointer (e.g. uninitialized), including just reading the value, results in undefined behavior.
I haven't dug into the standard, but I think your code is valid and the standard library implementation shipped with MSVC 2013 is faulty.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think 17.6.4.9 [res.on.arguments] clearly states that function asking for an array need to be passed a pointer which behaves as if it points to the first element of an array, i.e., that a null-pointer is not a valid argument. `std::basic_istream<...>::read()` asks for its first parameter to be an array. I don't thing MSVC 2013 is fault in that respect.

Comment: @DietmarKühl is the behavior then undefined *according to, and cited by, the standard*? Sorry, but I find it hard to fathom. The very text you cited from the standard states "all address calculations and accesses to objects", exactly *zero* of which would/should be done with a sequence length of zero. As an oddity addendum, is `read(&ch, sizeof(char))`, considered an "array" as well, or is that covered in the elided text you mentioned, or would that also be non-compliant in accordance with your assessment?

Comment: @WhozCraig: the easy one is `&ch`: in the section on expressions it is stated that the address of an object is considered to behave like an array of one element. I read the constraint as allowing the implementation to first form a reference to the destination and then check whether there is a need to store a value into it. If arrays are required that is OK, if null pointers are allowed it is not.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I can certainly see how that would be one way to read it. Regarding `&ch`, I would have to hunt for it, but one of my first answers on this site years ago was summarily harpooned when in response to an array-load question to a single var, I suggested something to the effect of `&var`, `&var+1` as the iterator range, which I had *thought* was legitimate use of a var as an "array of one object". I've been on eggshells for such associations since. Anyway, it would have helped had the standard been even a little on the NULL subject, but at least its good brain food. Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the relevant section on the array processing of objects is 5.7 [expr.add] paragraph 4: "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type." (where _these operator_ are operators + and -) This statement shows that `&var` and `&var + 1` indeed _is_ a legitimate iterator range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the standard says about `std::basic_istream<...>::read()` in 27.7.2.3 [istream.unformatted] paragraphs 30 and 31 (emphasis is mine):

> ```
> basic_istream<charT,traits>& read(char_type* s, streamsize n);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1). After constructing a `sentry` object, if `!good()` calls `setstate(failbit)` which may throw an exception, and return. Otherwise extracts characters and stores them into successive locations of an **array whose first element is designated by** `s`. Characters are extracted and stored until either of the following occurs:
>
> - `n` characters are stored;
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls `setstate(failbit | eofbit)`, which may throw `ios_base::failure`).
>
> *Returns*: `*this`.

When a function is described as taking array as argument, there are some constraints on what can be passed according to 17.6.4.9 [res.on.arguments] paragraph 1 (elided text applies to other entities):

> Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions defined in the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>
> - If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function or a pointer invalid for its intended use), the behavior is undefined.
> - If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer actually passed to the function shall have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (**that would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array**) are in fact valid.
> - ...

Actual arrays cannot be empty according to 8.3.4 [dcl.array] paragraph 1 (note that the case where the constant expression is absent yields an array of unspecified size which still gets a non-zero size eventually):

> ... If the constant-expression is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type std::size_t and its value shall be greater
>   than zero. ...

Since a null pointer cannot point to a non-empty array functions expecting an array being passed do expect a non-null pointer. Put differently, I think the assertion you observed is entirely in order, giving defined behavior to a use which has undefined behavior according to the standard: a null pointer even with a zero size passed to `read()` yield undefined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: So basically the standard allows an implementation to dereference the pointer even if I don't see a legitimate use of that when count equals zero. Great answer, thanks!